# Pppoe wireless connection, Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: wireless, ethernet, pppoe

I recently bought a new computer (Asus 1015 cx) with Ubuntu (12.4) as preinstalled system. My problem is with the internet. The computer connects just fine to the free wifi we have at home, but in college, we have a little bit different system. There is wifi, but it is not free - everyone receives a user name and a password. I cant manage to estabilish this Pppoe connection - the computer "sees" where can it connect, but I dont know where to write my username and password. It is not the DSL connection, what I have already tried. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but consider changing security type in connection settings. 
Select your wi-fi icon and then connection settings. On the Wireless tab select the connection you want and press edit. In the Wireless Security tab select LEAP from security and give your username and password.